# Is it possible to remove Steam from Plank while running?

Tags: plank, steam

is there a way to remove steam from dock but leave it minimized system tray? 
Found a topic on it however he didnt explain how he did it https://elementaryforums.com/index.php?threads/steam-x-button-minimizes-to-both-dock-and-the-top-panel.204/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.

You'll need to set the `$STEAM_FRAME_FORCE_CLOSE` environment variable before run Steam. There's a couple ways to do that. The easiest I found is to add the following to the end of `~/.profile`:

`export STEAM_FRAME_FORCE_CLOSE=1`

Then end your session and log in again. That should do the trick.